# Enterprise Mobility Manager - " Authentication Failed " issue on Mobile Phone

Tags: authentication, mdm

While I'm trying to register with my phone, I'm getting this error:

> Authentication Failed

**UPDATE 3.18.14;**
Okay , i compiled .apk file correctly with correct .bks file .Still i'm getting same error ! Should i change hosts file in my phone(samsung NOTE 3) ?

**NOTES:**

- In application conf, server address: `192.168.1.100`
- I can connect on mobile browser with `https://192.168.1.100:9443`

Answer (score 0):

Just execute this command.

> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore CA.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12
>   -destkeystore wso2mobilemdm.jks

CA needs to be the one you have used to sign your SSL certificate.

Comment: So , How can i convert .jks file to .bks file ? According to my researches , converting wtih rename method not correct way to converting them.

Comment: Yes its not the best way to rename it. You can use http://portecle.sourceforge.net/ to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

try creating all certificate in one folder.before creating ,just copy wso2carbon.jsk and client-truststore.jks in that folder.
try only single password wherever ask. but in last step use wso2_mobile when it ask.
copy wso2carbon.jsk, client-truststore.jks and wso2mobilemdm.jks from that folder to repository/resources/security folder to overwrite.
then in that folder copy bcprov-jdk15on-149.jar and run following command in that folder.

keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -keystore emm_truststore.bks -storetype bks -storepass wso2carbon -file ca_cert.pem -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath ./bcprov-jdk15on-149.jar
 thats it you will see emm_truststore.bks in that folder.